# ¿Cómo condicionar un JOIN en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo el siguiente problema. Tengo una tabla que relaciona dos IDs de usuarios entre sí. Donde existe un usuario `origen` y un usuario `destino`.

Para poder traer todos los registros de un usuario, por ejemplo, el usuario 10, sin importar si 10 es `origen` o `destino` hago lo siguiente:

```sql
SELECT * FROM amistad
WHERE origen = 10 OR destino = 10;
```

Lo cual me regresa algo como lo siguiente:

```
| origen | destino |
|--------|---------|
|   10   |   11    |
|   10   |   12    |
|   10   |   13    |
|   14   |   10    |
|   15   |   10    |
```

Quiero obtener los datos de usuario de la persona que no sea 10, es decir, hacer un JOIN a la tabla de usuario usando el ID que no sea 10, sin importar si es `destino` o `origen`.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM amistad AS a
JOIN usuario AS u ON u.usuario_id = ?????????
WHERE a.origen = 58 OR a.destino = 58;
```

Donde en `?????????` busco una instrucción para indicar al JOIN que usará el ID de la columna `origen` o `destino`, donde el valor sea diferente a 10

Comment: Deberias agregar la estructura de las tablas

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar dos lecturas a la misma tabla con dos LEFT JOIN y en función de que uno u otro resuelva el resultado esperado, escoger su valor mediante la función Coalesce.

```
SELECT a.*, Coalesce(u.usuario_id, d.usuario_id) as usuario
FROM amistad AS a
LEFT JOIN usuario AS u ON u.usuario_id = a.origen and u.usuario_id <> 58
LEFT JOIN usuario AS d ON d.usuario_id = a.destino and d.usuario_id <>58
WHERE a.origen = 58 OR a.destino = 58;
```

Otra opción es utilizar un coalesce en la union descartando los valores a buscar.

```
SELECT a.*, u.*
FROM amistad AS a
JOIN (Select usuario_id from Usuario where usuario_id <> 58 )
as u on u.usuario_id = coalesce(NULLIF(a.origen,58), NULLIF(a.destino,58))
WHERE a.origen = 58 OR a.destino = 58;
```

De manera que hacemos la union con coalesce, pero le quitamos al conjunto a, para la union, los que correspondan con 58

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from amistad as a
join(select * 
     from usuario       
     where usuario.id <> 10) as u on 
     u.id = ???
```

Lo que se hace aquí es una **subconsulta** dentro de la **cláusula join** que devuelve todos los usuarios con **id** distinto de **10**, esta consulta se maneja como si fuera una tabla. Analiza este código y trata de adaptarlo al tuyo.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer una unión de los resultados, por ejemplo:

```
select origen as amigo
  from amistad
 where destino = 10
union all
select destino
  from amistad
 where origen = 10
```

Te va a devolver la misma lista de antes, pero solo los usuarios con los que está relacionado el 10 y en una sola columna:

```
| amigo  |
|--------|
|   11   |
|   12   |
|   13   |
|   14   |
|   15   |
```

Ya con esto, podrías hacer un join a la tabla de usuarios o un `where id in`:

```
select usuario.*
  from usuario
       inner join (select origen as amigo from amistad where destino = 58
                   union all
                   select destino from amistad where origen = 58
                  ) as amigo
          on usuario.usuario_id = amigo.amigo
```

o

```
select usuario.*
  from usuario
 where usuario.usuario_id in (select origen as amigo from amistad where destino = 58
                              union all
                              select destino from amistad where origen = 58
                             )
```